# Custom Long Date Format - C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a drop down menu containing several different dates, where one will be selected based in if it matches a date in an Excel sheet I'm using. The dates in the dropdown menu are of the format `Wednesday, August 9, 2016`.

Now my plan was to convert the Excel data to a long date format and compare the two; however, I noticed that C#'s long date format includes a zero preceding the day, like `Wednesday, August 09, 2016`.

Is there a way that I can remove that extra 0 in front of the 9 when converting to a long date format in C#? Or is there another method I should try.

Comment: Why don't you use regex compare?

Comment: Use the .ToString of the date with this format string "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy".

Comment: @Kevin: Ah, I wasn't even aware you could format dates that way. My research was not extensive enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
mydate.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your format is fixed that way, you can just use a [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
date.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this format can do the job:

```
String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd,MMMM,d,yyyy",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
   // Wednesday, August 9, 2016
```